# What is the "rtol" parameter for the root finding function scipy.optimize.brentq?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm having trouble understanding what the "rtol" parameter for brentq does. The help information is located here :

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html#scipy.optimize.brentq

> **rtol** : number, optional The routine converges when a root is known to
>   lie within rtol times the value returned of the value returned. Should
>   be >= 0. Defaults to np.finfo(float).eps * 2.

Now I'm not exactly sure what this description is saying. Could anybody elaborate on how rtol controls the convergence tolerance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a number `x`, if the root finder can guarantee that there is a root `x'` such that `|x - x'| <= x*rtol`, `x` is deemed close enough to report it as the root.